# How Can I Pass a Variable Parameter to A Windows RemoteApp?

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-server-2016, windows-terminal-services, remoteapp

I have published a remote app, MyApp.exe, from Server X. MyApp.exe can be launched with a variable optional parameter. That parameter can have a larger number of different values.

I have downloaded the RDP file from the gateway website that Server X publishes. I named the rdp file MyApp.rdp.

Is there anyway to pass a parameter to MyApp.exe running on Server X when I launch the RDP file? Something like this would be the most natural:

```
MyApp.RDP XYZ
```

This would run MyApp.exe on Server X passing it parameter XYZ.

I've looked all around the town and I can't find a clear yes or no or how-to for this question.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to change command-line arguments in a signed RDP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168788/is-there-a-way-to-change-command-line-arguments-in-a-signed-rdp-file) – you must change the `remoteapplicationcmdline:s:` in the rdp file or enable file associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Edit RDP File programmatically (See [Is there a way to change command-line arguments in a signed RDP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168788/is-there-a-way-to-change-command-line-arguments-in-a-signed-rdp-file))
2. Use a file association
3. Use the `/REMOTECMDLINE` parameter of `mstsc` 
   Ex: `mstsc /REMOTECMDLINE:foo path\to\app.rdp` will result in `app.exe foo` on the server

   You must remove the `remoteapplicationcmdline:s:` parameter from the rdp file lest you get the error message "This RDP file has settings that cannot be overridden by command line."  You must also have "Allow any command-line parameters" selected on the app configuration on the server.
4. Use the `/REMOTEFILE` parameter of `mstsc`